# What are the gigantic *.CFS files all about in Eclipse workspace plugin folder?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, maven, workspace, nexus

I started to notice my WD drive getting full and ran a size:gigantic file search on it.  It has turned up several files here:

`F:\SCOTT-SHARED-DESKTOP\My Documents\JPA_SPRING_STRUTS\.metadata\.plugins\org.maven.ide.eclipse\nexus\d9d714e11cb097b3ffcec91cccc65d3e_58.cfs`

that exceed 189,992 KB (189 MB)!

Anyone know about these rascals?

Comment: I guess you downloaded half the internet using maven and nexus did a good job indexing your jars ;.)

Comment: I think the answer from PomCompot is spot on and should be the one accepted as it clearly outlines where the files come from.

Comment: Thanks for posting. Otherwise I'd have assumed it was https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFS_(file_format)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stacker points out, each of these seem to be a Lucene segment file, with [Compound File format](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/fileformats.html). If you want to see what is inside, you can open them with [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/).

Comment: I think what the original poster might have wanted to know, is how to configure Eclipse so these large files don't re-appear after we get rid of them - I have 16 eclipse workspaces for different sets of projects, each with a 50+ Meg ..\nexus\..CFS file.  Is there some kind of 'don't index' setting per maven dependency?  Some of these might be handy, but certainly not so many copies... any way to get it to combine them?

Answer (score 52):

Indeed, it's Nexus indexes. You can disable partially or totally Nexus indexes retrieval by right clicking on repositories in the Maven repositories view and checking/uncheking Disable Index Details/Enable Minimum Index/Full Index Enabled (options with M2Eclipse 0.12).

Hereunder a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Just when I thought the m2e plugin couldn't be more of a piece of crap, it goes and proves me wrong, again!

Comment: This plugin has been quite a nightmare in the past, but the latest version (since 11.x) is a real progress. For their defense, combining the Maven build lifecycle with Eclipse incremental build is not a piece of cake.

Comment: @PomCompot Am I supposed to wait for it to delete the files? Or should I do it manually?

Comment: @RafaelJ You should delete them if the size matters for you. As far as I know, they wouldn't be deleted automatically.

Comment: According to the useful [doc reference](http://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/repository-sect-repo-view.html#d5e1169) provided by @teja, the difference between "minimum" and "full" index is that the latter includes all contained class names. In my workspace, the "min" index is still some 4.8GB...

Answer (score 32):

You might also consider unchecking the checkbox (under `Window` menu, `Preferences`, `Maven`):

[image: Download repository index updates at startup]

Comment: Also a good idea, this repository index download dramatically slows down startup. It should be noted that having no Maven indexes prevents some artifact search through the Eclipse UI (completion in POM for instance).

Comment: yes, it would be good to have an alternative allowing to use

http://search.maven.org/#api

to search without a local index.

Answer (score 3):

Every repository that m2eclipse uses is indexed by the Nexus Indexer. If m2eclipse is using a remote repository, it will download a Nexus index from the remote repository. If m2eclipse is managing a local repository (local or workspace) it will use the open source Nexus indexer to create and maintain a local index. This index is what allows you to quickly search for and locate dependencies by artifactId, groupId, version, or classname.

http://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/repository-sect-repo-view.html#d5e1169