# Why does Eclipse maven produce huge .cfs files for no reason?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, nexus, m2e

I suddenly found that the plugins folder of my Eclipse workspace was huge, and I discovered the following files:

- ...\EclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.core\nexus\d5024e88244f4087c1f73b4a8fae2df4_i.cfs
  ~200MB
- E:\.m2\repository\.cache\m2e\1.0.100\d9d714e11cb097b3ffcec91cccc65d3e\min_n.cfs and also _r.cfs
  ~200MB each

Before finding these huge files I didn't even know what Maven was, I didn't choose to install it (must have come with Indigo upgrade) and I haven't ever used it or told it to index or cache anything.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199743/what-are-the-gigantic-cfs-files-all-about-in-eclipse-workspace-plugin-folder) and googled extensively, but can't work out why maven or nexus is even doing *anything*!

Could someone please explain to me why it creates these files in the first place, especially without me even using it or telling/allowing it to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any projects that use maven to control their build process? Perhaps open source projects that you've grabbed the source for?

Comment: Not as far as I know, I didn't even know what Maven was before I discovered these, and all my projects in my workspace are ones that I created from scratch.
The only things I have changed are installing plugins PyDev, ProDT and ML-Dev, whilst messing around with Python, Prolog and ML.

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/a/6732819/874076> best answers this.

Comment: This answers the general question for which thank you, however it does not explain why they're there in a workspace where I have not got any projects using maven at all.

Answer (score 5):

I just have the same problem. I just did some test coding and found that 250MB are stored in a file

...eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.core\nexus\d9d714e11cb097b3ffcec91cccc65d3e_j.cfs

i found this:

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg01708.html

> m2e caches lucene index in two places. Per-workspace indexes are
>   stored under .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core/nexus and there
>   is also global cache in ~/.m2/repository/.cache/m2e/${m2e.version}.
>
> Try cleaning the caches and see if the problem goes away.

Well - but that doesn't still till what and why it is stored there.